# How create new sheets with specific names and copy specific values into new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with a list of names(names.xlsm), I want to create another new excel file(separate.xlsx) with different sheets. The name of each sheet in separate.xlsx is a name in names.xlsx and the first cell of each sheet is the same name value.

'''VBA

```
Sub copy_name()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Set mybook = Workbooks("names.xlsm")

    Set MyRange = mybook.Sheets("names").Range("A2:A6") 'eg. five names'

    Dim target As Workbook
    Set target = Workbooks("separate.xlsx")

    i = 1
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Set ws = target.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) ' create new worksheet in target file
    ws.Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    target.Sheets(MyCell.Value).Cells(1, 1) = MyCell 'copy the value of Mycell to target sheets
    i = i + 1
    Next

    Set mybook = Nothing
    Set target = Nothing
End Sub
```

'''
Here is my code. It keeps showing errors and I do not know how to debug.

Comment: Where does it give you an error? For debugging you can press F8 and the procedure willgo line by line

Comment: @Damian The error shows in line:Set ws = target.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

Comment: Change this: `target.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))`  for this: `target.Sheets.Add(After:=target.Sheets(target.Sheets.Count))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create the worksheet and name it in one line. No need to create it and then name it.
2. You need to fully qualify your objects
3. I am assuming that the workseets with the same name as in the `names.xlsm` do not exist in `separate.xlsx`. If it does then you will have to handle that separately.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbNames As Workbook, wbSep As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set wbNames = Workbooks("names.xlsm")
    Set wbSep = Workbooks("separate.xlsx")

    Set rng = wbNames.Sheets("Names").Range("A2:A6")

    For Each aCell In rng
        With wbSep
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)).Name = aCell.Value
            .Worksheets(aCell.Value).Cells(1, 1).Value = aCell.Value
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```